# Android AudioTrack extremely slow on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec, audiotrack

I have a system decoding MP3 audio with `MediaExtractor`, converting it with `MediaCodec` and playing it with `AudioTrack`.  On most devices it works fine, but on the Samsung Galaxy S3 and Samsung Galaxy Tab, some users report extremely slow audio playback.  I can't reproduce it on an emulator or physical devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788496/android-audio-too-fast-on-some-devices-with-mediacodec-and-audiotrack is a continuation of this issue?

Comment: It's a related, but different issue.  This one relates to dealing with hardware that does the right thing - that one relates to hardware that does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trouble, it turns out that the issue was with my use of `MediaFormat`.  On some devices, the MediaFormat returned by `MediaCodec` is not the same as the one returned by `MediaExtractor`.  Frame rates, etc., may change.  Instead of instantiating `AudioTrack` with the MediaFormat returned by MediaExtractor, it was necessary to wait until decoding began.  At that point, `MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer()` will return `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`. `MediaCodec.getOutputFormat()` can then be used return the correct MediaFormat with which to initialize the AudioTrack.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can you paste an example of "early" and "late" MediaFormats into the answer? I'm curious what the difference is.

Comment: I actually don't have an affected device, so I don't know the details.  Since the voice was slow, it must be a faster bit rate, mono to stereo, or possibly more bits per sample.  A few people have reported, however, that playback is now too fast.  I'll post back here when I figure out what is going on with that.

Comment: @fadden: I've seen some cases of AAC decoders decode mono input data into stereo at least. (This is a common phenomenon with many decoders when given HE-AACv1 data actually, but in my case it happened with either plain AAC-LC, or AAC-LD.)